# How do I write unencoded Json to my View and emit the first and last quote

Tags: javascript, json, string

I am using google maps JavaScript api to display GeoJson data stored on my SQL server as a string.

I iterate through the model and return the GeoJson to the google Script,

```
            foreach (var item1 in item.state.Geojsonstates)
        {
            @:map.data.addGeoJson(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@item1.GeoJsonString)));

        }
```

this returns the following HTML snippet,

```
map.data.addGeoJson("{\n\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\n\"features
```

for the Json to be valid I need to emit the first quote and the last quote from the string,

```
map.data.addGeoJson(" <-----this quote needs to be emitted
```

are there any overloaders for the,

```
Json.Encode())
```

function to emit the quote wrapper ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using "emit" when you mean to say "omit" ?

Comment: @dan08 good question. Having JSON _without_ the quotes surrounding the entire thing is not only valid but I think _having_ the quotes would make it invalid. In other words, I think `"{name: "myJson", id: 1}"` would actually choke a lot of parsers. So is this a question of _including_ the start and end double quote or _excluding_ them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
@:map.data.addGeoJson(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@item1.GeoJsonString)));
```

to

```
@:map.data.addGeoJson(@Html.Raw(@item1.GeoJsonString));
```